# How to mock some methods only throw exception for the first time and then do nothing, with specs2?

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

In specs2, we can mock a method and let it throw exception:

```
class Hello {
   def say():Unit = println("Hello, world")
}

val hello = mock[Hello]
hello.say() throws new RuntimeException("something wrong")
```

But how to make it just throw the first time, and then always do nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a mockito question, not a specs2 one.
From the mockito documentation:

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
   .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
   .thenReturn("foo");
```

Alternative, shorter version of consecutive stubbing:

```
 when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
   .thenReturn("one", "two", "three");
```

Comment: So I can't use specs2 DSL for it anymore :(

Comment: You can, specs2 has a Mockito integration, you add the trait to use it (you did already). But there's a difference between Expectations and Assertions.

Answer (score 0):

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException("something wrong")).doNothing().when(hello).say()
```